# Can't get Apache mod_rewrite to ignore a directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get Apache mod_rewrite to ignore certain directories. Here's part of my httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(img|css|js)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

If I go to http://example.com/img/random_path, I still see the error message generated by index.php (rather than the default error page).

Comment: Do you have .htaccess inside `/img/` also?

Comment: use the skip flag `S=1` to avoid next rule

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this rule condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/img\/
```

before your rewrite rules. It prevent rewriting for urls contain "/img/" string.